# Можно ли использовать LiveData напрямую при запросе к бд

Tags: android, mvvm, rxjava, android-room, livedata

Пытаюсь попробовать mvvm и LiveData, у меня есть запрос в базу данных Room

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM User ")
fun getAllUsers(): LiveData<MutableList<User>>

@Query("SELECT * FROM User ")
fun getAllUsersRx(): Flowable<MutableList<User>>
```

из ViewModel вызываю их и все приходит в обоих случаях, но если через rx все работает в другом треде, то в случае с LiveData все должно происходить в mainThread. Но тогда почему Room не выдает ошибку IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread? И правильно ли в таком случае напрямую запрашивать данные у Room использую LiveData, или нужно самостаятельно перенести операцию в другой поток?

Comment: насколько я помню, в Room нужно обязательно реализовать операции записи/чтения в параллельном потоке иначе выдает ошибку

Comment: @pavlofff в этом и вопрос, я не реализую параллельный поток, посылаю запрос из mainThread, данные приходят корректно и ошибка не вызывается, а вроде как должна, так как у LiveData нету механизма управлениями потоками(если я все верно понял). Поэтому хочу понять почему так происходит, и как правильно настроить взаимодействие между Room и LiveData

Comment: Room использует другой поток, а результат уже помещает в LiveData. Собственно для этого LiveData и нужна, чтоб в нее можно было помещать результат асинхронной работы.

Comment: @VitalyTomashevsky с вашей наводки я внимательней перечитал доки, и нашел об этом информацию. Я бы хотел отметить ответ как верный с прикреплением этой ссылки [ссылка](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#use_livedata_with_room)   но не знаю как правильно это сделать

Comment: Если вы нашли решение, вы можете сами ответить на ваш вопрос, нажав кнопку "ответить на собственный вопрос" и оформить ответ. Вот посмотрел свой проект с Room. При реализации методов insert и delete в ViewModel студия настаивает, что эти методы должны выполнятся в параллельном потоке и не собирает проект без этого.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Room использует другой поток, а результат уже помещает в LiveData. Собственно для этого LiveData и нужна, чтоб в нее можно было помещать результат асинхронной работы  [ссылка](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#use_livedata_with_room)